# Python log.txt making fancy. grep/regex

Tags: python, regex, email, grep

There are a log.txt.

"[25-Feb-2016 11:27:16 +0200]: Login failed .... 212.153.100.19 Get/.... emailaddress@email.com"........

How can i write a script which can grep or regex me only the dates/IP addresses and email addresses and write it out to an other .txt.

The most important thing is that i need dates and the corresponding IPs and emails.

I try it to with the next code, but it is segment all of the data ..

```
import os
import re
import datetime


filename = 'log.txt'
newfilename = 'output.txt'


if os.path.exists(filename):
    data = open(filename,'r')
    bulkemails = data.read()


else:
    print "File not found."
    raise SystemExit


r = re.compile(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\b')
results = r.findall(bulkemails)    

emails = ""   
for x in results:
    emails += str(x)+"\n"   



ip = re.compile(r'\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b')
result = ip.findall(bulkemails)

ip =""
for y in result:
    ip += str(y)+"\n"


dt = re.compile(r'(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})')
result = dt.findall(bulkemails)

dt =""
for z in result:
    dt += str(z)+"\n"




def writefile():
    f = open(newfilename, 'w')
    f.write(emails + ip + dt)
    f.close()
    print "File written."


def overwrite_ok():
    response = raw_input("Are you sure you want to overwrite "+str(newfilename)+"? Yes or No\n")
    if response == "Yes":
        writefile()
    elif response == "No":
        print "Aborted."
    else:
        print "Please enter Yes or No."
        overwrite_ok()


if os.path.exists(newfilename):
    overwrite_ok()      
else: 
    writefile()
```

So i whould like to same output.txt what is included the next :

25-Feb-2016 11:27:16 +0200] -- 212.153.100.19 -- emailaddress@email.com"

25-Feb-2016 11:27:16 +0200] -- 212.153.100.10 -- emailaddress1@email.com"

25-Feb-2016 11:27:16 +0200] -- 212.153.100.11 -- emailaddress2@email.com"

Thanks for help, and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a regex with three groups, one for the time, one for the IP and one for the email.

```
import re
my_regex = re.compile(r".+?(\d{2}-\w+-\d{4}).+?(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).+?\b([\w.\d]+@[\w.\d]+)(?:\b|$)")
with open("somefile") as f_logs:
    logs = f_logs.readlines()
for line in logs:
    my_regex.sub(r"[\1] -- \2 -- \3",line)
```

You can check it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uyl2Rj/1)